# MySQL between and or?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query for selecting orders and I want to select between two dates. But I also want to select all orders that are of one of 3 or 4 statuses. I have the following

```
SELECT *
WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
       AND order_status = 'pending'
        OR order_status = 'processing'
        OR order_status = 'payment_received'
        OR order_status = 'completed'
```

But the problem is it seems to select everything with order status of one of those 4. And completely ignores the `BETWEEN` if I change the order of the `BETWEEN` to be after the order status `OR`'s it still includes orders with a created timestamp after the `'1322884800'`

Where should I put the between or how can I do this to select orders between X and Y with a order status of one of 4 (or 3, or 2, or 1) value(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `order_status` clause in parentheses (or better yet, use an IN list).

```
SELECT *
WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
       AND (order_status = 'pending'
        OR order_status = 'processing'
        OR order_status = 'payment_received'
        OR order_status = 'completed')
```

The way you have it now, the precedence is being interpreted as:

```
SELECT *
WHERE  (created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
       AND order_status = 'pending')
        OR order_status = 'processing'
        OR order_status = 'payment_received'
        OR order_status = 'completed'
```

This would evaluate to true if any of the last three order status are found, regardless of the `created` date.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
WHERE
    created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800' AND
    order_status IN ('pending', 'processing', 'payment_received', 'completed')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a precedence issue:

```
SELECT *
WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
   AND (order_status = 'pending'
    OR order_status = 'processing'
    OR order_status = 'payment_received'
    OR order_status = 'completed')
```

The OR statements aren't being evaluated in the order you expect - put brackets around the OR part to make sure that they're evaluated properly. You can also do:

```
SELECT *
WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
   AND order_status IN ('pending','processing','payment_received','completed')
```

Which is a little neater.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate the ORs. Or use something like this:

`SELECT *
WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
       AND order_status IN ('pending', 'processing','payment_received', 'completed')`

Note, not checked for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
       AND ( order_status = 'pending'
        OR order_status = 'processing'
        OR order_status = 'payment_received'
        OR order_status = 'completed' )
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly define the precedence by using brackets:

```
 SELECT *
 WHERE  created BETWEEN '1296360000' AND '1322884800'
   AND ( order_status = 'pending'
    OR order_status = 'processing'
    OR order_status = 'payment_received'
    OR order_status = 'completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
SELECT * 
WHERE created >= '1296360000' 
AND created <= '1322884800' 
AND order_status in ("pending", "processing", "payment_received", "completed")
```